# Question about generalizing Cauchy identity

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, linear-groups

One of the Cauchy identities says that
$$\prod_{i,j}(1+x_iy_j) = \sum_\lambda s_\lambda (x_1, \cdots,x_m) s_{\lambda'} 
 (y_1, \cdots,y_n) $$

Where $\lambda$ is a Young diagram, $\lambda'$ is the transpose diagram, and $s$ is the Schur polynomial.

I would like to elevate $x_i$ and $y_j$ to $d$ dimensional vectors $\vec x_i$ and $\vec y_j$. Is there any generalized Cauchy identity, or any other nice closed form, for $$\prod_{i,j}(1+\vec x_i\cdot \vec y_j),$$ with $d>1$?